# When ever I write something in Arabic or Persian in Adobe Illustrator CS5.1 the word do not appear on the screen?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, cs5

When ever I write something in Arabic or Persian in Adobe Illustrator CS5.1 the word do not appear on the screen?
But I can see the word which I have written in layer names.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the font you're using is not supported by Illustrator.  I would suggest trying another Arabic font.  Reference: "[Arabic and Hebrew type](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/arabic-hebrew.html)"

> Legacy font support
>
> Fonts that have been traditionally used (for example, AXT fonts) can
>   continue to be used in this release of the software. However, it is
>   recommended that newer Open Type fonts be used for text-based
>   elements. Missing Glyph Protection (Edit > Preferences > Advanced
>   Type) is enabled by default. Text is handled automatically, where
>   glyphs are not available in the font you are using.

If you still have an issue please edit your question with more information.